# video with zoom incrusted in a modal window outbounds the limits of container

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, video, bootstrap-modal

I have a web, with a datatable with movementst. This movements have a button to open a modal window, and is here where i have the problem.

when the modal opens two videos from different angles of movements beggining to play (i change this videos for other standard and public). This is OK.

But when i want to zoom with wheel mouse event, and i want to drag the video zoomed, it can be outside of the container, and i want that the video stays in the container.

I attach a jsfiddle with the case:

```
(https://jsfiddle.net/pililagorda/y4v7z2c0/5/)
```

Could you help me please?

Thanks in advance
Sorry for the inconveniences
Kind regards